# What's the difference between discarding a changeset and keep target version when resolving conflicts in Microsoft TFS Source Control

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, merge-conflict-resolution, tfvc, changeset

when you are merging your changeset in Microsoft TFS Source Control, your changes may come into a conflict, then if it couldn't become auto-resolved, you have to resolve it by yourself. or you can take source version or keep target version.
another workaround is to discard your changeset.

"keep target version" and "discarding changeset", both of them are saying that the target version is the correct one that will be kept.
So, what's the difference between them exactly? why both of them exist?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the subtle way the history is kept. When you "Keep target version" a *change ticket* is stored with the merge telling it to ignore the differences in the future.

When you "undo" the changes in the merge, no ticket is logged and a future merge between those branches/files will propose to merge those changes again.

You'd perform the second (undo) if you have changes that are not yet ready to merge to the target branch, but were (accidentally) selected as part of the merge action.

You'd perform the first (Take/Keep) if you want that version to become leading and do not want to merge those differences in the future.

Many developers do not understand the difference and issues can occur when you have long-living branches, like `dev` & `main`. If people use "keep target" a lot, a merge between dev and main would not show any changes to merge, but a diff between the two may bring a lot of differences to light. In general I guide teams towards undoing the changes vs picking "keep mine" or "take theirs".

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. What do you mean by "undo" exactly ? I think It's equivalent to "Rollback" in TFS. that is different from "discard". I mean this command exactly: tf merge /discard

Comment: No undo is 'undo pending changes' it undoes the merge for that specific file. Discard changeset from the command line is the equivalent of 'take theirs', saying that these changes will never need to be merged.

Comment: so the answer will be "There is no difference", between discarding a changeset and keep target version. Isn't it ?

Comment: The only difference is that discarding a changeset, discards the changes for all files in that changeset. Keep target can be done at file level. So you have the options to: `Keep target`, `keep source`, `undo pending changes` on a per file level and `discard changeset` at the changeset level.